# using UnityConfiguration

Tags: .net, unity-container

I'm using [UnityConfiguration](https://github.com/thedersen/unityconfiguration) with an MVC application and I'm trying to register some types using the code

```
container.Configure(a => a.Scan(b => b.Include(
              t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(ActionFilterAttribute)))));
```

But it does not seem to register by types. 
True, I could also use

```
GetType()
     .Assembly
     .GetTypes()
     .Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(ActionFilterAttribute)))
     .ToList()
     .ForEach(r => container.RegisterType(r));
```

but it does not have the same readability.

Maybe I don't understand what the "configure" (extension) method is supposed to do.

Thanks,
florin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scanner is used when you want to automatically register types by a convention instead of manually configure the container for every type.

As a minimum, when using the scanner, you have to specify the assemblies you want to scan as well as which convention you want to use:

```
container.Configure(c => c.Scan(scan =>
{
    scan.AssembliesInBaseDirectory();
    scan.With<FirstInterfaceConvention>();
    scan.Include(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(ActionFilterAttribute)));
}));
```

A couple of things worth mentioning:

1. If the built-in conventions doesn't suit you, you can make your own simply by creating a class that implements the `IAssemblyScannerConvention` interface and replace the `FirstInterfaceConvention` in the example with your type.
2. By using `scan.Include(...)` you implicitly excludes all other types from being registered.
3. It looks like you are trying to register a concrete class (attribute). This is not necessary in Unity as it can resolve concrete classes without them being registered first.

Hope this helps!

-Thomas

Comment: Could there be a reason why unity would not resolve my type? I try to get it using the MVC dependency resolver which in turn asks unity for it.
Could this be because I have "another scanner" run on this assembly to register classes using the FirstInterfaceConvention? (scan.Assembly(typeof(T).Assembly);
scan.With<FirstInterfaceConvention>().IgnoreInterfacesOnBaseTypes();)

Comment: found the answer: i'm using Unity.Mvc3 library and in it's implementation of the DependentyResolver if has the condition that the type is registered (makes sense, right?).
And I'm getting by instance using the DependecyResolver.Current.GetService<myType>(). I'm thinking if I should register all my needed types (probable) or rewrite my own version of the DependencyResolver which uses more of Unity's capabilities.